# Are questions about food criticism on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Some concepts that related to 
[food critic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_critic) such as [gastronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastronomy), [food studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_studies), [culinary arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culinary_arts) also seem to be absent in here. The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't explicitly mention this topic.

Here is my draft question:

> In the movie *Ratatouille*, there is a scene that the food critic, Ego, describes a perspective as "fresh, clear, well-seasoned". As "fresh" and "well-seasoned" typically go along with food criticism, I wonder if "clear" is as well. If that's correct, can you provide some examples for it? Since this is a word play, I understand that "clear" may not.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you just want to know what a word would mean when used to describe food?

Comment: @Cascabel yes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say:

- Food criticism in general is not on topic, since it's not really anything to do with preparing food. We don't do recipe reviews or restaurant reviews, and food criticism is pretty much just that.
- Food *vocabulary* is on topic, since describing the food we might make is a pretty normal part of preparing food. We help people understand recipes, and I'd assume that includes understanding a recipe's description of the resulting dish, for example.

Your specific question could probably be asked in the latter form - there's really not much need to deem it about "food criticism", you're just saying that you have two words that could describe a dish, and you're wondering if the third also could.